# Can not get to suggested edits review page

Tags: bug, status-completed

For the last few days (not sure of exactly how many) I have been unable to review any suggested edits. Currently the little bubble is showing me that there are 4, but when I click on this button it tries to go to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits but then gives me the error:

> 504 Gateway Time-out
>
> The server didn't respond in time.

This is happening at home, at work, and on my phone.

On my phone I get a slightly different error message, something about my browser not responding in time. I suspect it is supposed to be the same 504 error though.

Comment: The link you provided points to Tag Wiki edits: is that intentional or are you talking about simple posts edits?

Comment: @clabacchio I believe this is a 10K+ user privilege. It is where you can see a list of all of the suggested edits and approve them.

Comment: I was about to submit this bug, was about to hit submit when this popped up. Glad it is not just me.

Comment: It is for the /review page in general, but like myself you found it trying to get rid of that annoying bubble of edits waiting for review.

Comment: @Kortuk I noticed it on Friday or Saturday from my phone, but I thought it was just my phone acting odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened cause this post: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/28255/1833 crashed our diff engine.

It crashed our Markdown engine cause we hit some sort of internal edge case, the body of the post has some irregular html, this is causing the Markdown engine to totally collapse.

Apologies, I rejected the edit, can the community (somebody with full edit rights) edit that post so it is valid markdown (kill all the tags).

We are also looking at fixing the underlying Markdown engine.

Comment: I wrote that post.  What is the malformed HTML?  I'd rather fix that than remove all the HTML formatting I put there to make it look that way I want it to look.  If I missed a closing tag or something, let me know or fix it yourself.