# Can't access review history because of HTTP 500

Tags: bug

I am trying to see the first revision of [this post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/28255/revisions).

When I click one the `1` to unroll the text, an image with three 'loading' dots `...` appears.

After a couple of seconds, a message appears in the developer console saying an HTTP 500 in `jquery.min.js:4`:

```
GET https://electronics.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/revisions/28255/ad5f0b0a-ec48-4f45-bc3a-11dc3fc33832/diff 500 ()
```

I was interested in seeing the first review to better understand why the post became community wiki.

I have the same problem with the 2nd review. The 3rd one works great.

I'm attaching screenshot.

Is this a bug ?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Related: [Can not get to suggested edits review page](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1037/can-not-get-to-suggested-edits-review-page)

There were nonstandard HTML tags used in such a way that the rendering engine gets very unhappy. The original version and probably the diff'd version 2 are probably affected. If you want to see the original content, the "source" tab shows it.

Honestly, I don't remember the reason it was turned into a community wiki, I think the current consensus is that it should be used incredibly selectively.

Comment: So it is a bug that hasn't been fixed since weeks ago, do I get it right ?

Comment: Looks like it's been about 5 years. It was enough of an edge case that it was low priority beyond breaking the site.